# Strace is not working in MIPS target

Tags: mips, embedded-linux

I am working an embedded board which has MIPS processor. I am facing an issue while executing strace on target.

*Build environment:*

```
glibc version: 2.3.2
gcc version: 3.4.4
strace version: 4.4.94 
linux version : 2.6.34.1
```

I have cross compiled strace for MIPS target and trying to run strace in the target. But strace is not working. I don't see any system call trace.

*Output of strace execution on target:*

```
#strace /bin/ls
(To be restarted).
#
```

I feel I am missing some configuration or flags to be configured to make strace working.

CFLAGS = "-D_REENTRANT -g -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -march=mips32r2 -mtune=mips32r2 -Wall -g -DHAVE_SERVICE_CTRL"

Please help me on this.

Comment: Thank you for you input. I have changed Optimizer flag from Os to -O in CFLAGS (CFLAGS="-D_REENTRANT -g -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -march=mips32r2 -O -Wall -DHAVE_SERVICE_CTRL"), now able to get system call trace but still output result gives some big return values.                                                     mode=open, "/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLYDIRd/4464388-717129012:01:268633712

Answer (score 0):

`strace` uses `ptrace()` system call in order to trace the target executable.
Perhaps your Linux distribution doesn't support `ptrace()`.
I would create a simple test program that calls `ptrace()` to see if it works or not.

Debugging will also be very helpful. You can set remote debugging with `gdb` and debug the target board from a PC.

Comment: After removing the optimizer flag in CFLAGS="-D_REENTRANT -g -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -march=mips32r2 -Wall" , strace is started working as excepted.